# New line not show when alert text returned by ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"; charset=GBK"%>
<%
 out.println("a\\nb");
%>
```

now in a web page, I call this jsp with ajax:

```
alert($.ajax({url:'test.jsp', async: false}).responseText.trim());
```

it alerts `a\n\b` in IE, how can I make it alert like this:

a
b

Comment: @SimoneGianni not works, just tested

Comment: Remove \\n, you are escaping the \ .. leave \n, only one backslash, it will output ascii 13 and 10, that should display in alert. Sorry for previous comment, i was assuming alert was not javascript alert but some html popup.

Comment: @Simonegianni please consider that make you comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing

```
out.println("a\\nb");
```

You are escaping the backslash, so this produces the string "a\nb".

To instead output a newline, don't escape it :

```
out.println("a\nb");
```

This will output the string "ab".

Since javascript alert takes a single string, and doesn't do HTML parsing or other escaping, the newline will be sent to output correctly.